# Is it possible to import rdl files into Power BI

Tags: sql, reporting-services, powerbi

Now we are on a process of converting few of our `ssrs reports` into Power BI. I wonder if there any option to import an entire report structure(`rdl files`) into power BI. please help me about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't. SSRS & Power BI are fundamentally different tools. If your SSRS reports are simple, then it shouldn't be hard to move the queries over to Power BI and then reproduce the same visuals (tables, charts, etc), though it would still look & feel very different.

Power BI has a focus on interactivity & data exploration that SSRS does not. As you convert reports, you'll likely want to update them to take advantage of features like slicers & cross-filtering & drill-downs.

On the other hand, SSRS has a lot of fine-tuning options that simply don't exist in Power BI (including an entire expression language). There are a lot of things you can do with SSRS that you can't easily recreate in Power BI (which is why a general conversion tool would be very difficult to write).

*A super-delayed response, I realize, so I'm curious as to how your conversion project worked out.*

Comment: thanks for the response...when we started the project there were no option to integrate ssrs reports with power bi...so we manually done the conversion ( we created visuals for each report as per requirement)..But, recently power bi has got the capability to include the ssrs reports ( i think we can view the reports in power bi, but cannot make it interactive )

Comment: With SSRS 2016, you can pin elements of an SSRS report to Power BI dashboards (though you can't publish the entire SSRS report to Power BI, it can link through to your local server). With the next version of SQL Server (not yet released), you will be able to publish & view Power BI reports in SSRS too. Adam Saxton has a good overview of the current capabilities here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhPQObqmMPc

Answer (score 7):

Import of SSRS reports (.rdl) is supported now in Power BI premium.

This feature is called as Paginated Reports.

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports-save-to-power-bi-service

I understand this is very late reply, but I guess it could help someone.